# Simple addition in vue data

Tags: object, vuejs2, calc, computed-properties

I want to add two numbers in vue

```
data() {
  return {
    details: {
        num1: 100,
        num2: 500,
        total: num1 + num2
}
  }
    }
```

Is this not possible and bad practice? I can create a computed but this as a temp shortcut would be useful.  Is it just the scope I have wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very bad practice!
In Vue.js you should always use computed properties for any calculation.

But in your case you should do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>{{details.total()}}</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      details: {
          num1: 100,
          num2: 500,
          total: () => this.details.num1 + this.details.num2
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
</script>
```